# How to remove all leading slashes in a string?

Tags: java

I have a string in Java, it starts with slashes, but the number of slashes is unknown. How can I remove all theses slashes at start?

For example:

```
String a="//abc";
```

Should output `abc`.

```
String b="////abc";
```

Should also output `abc`.

Comment: How did you try it? Show your code

Comment: Read the javadoc for replaceAll method in String class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple pattern for that:

```
private static final Pattern HEADING_SLASHES = Pattern.compile("^/+");

// ...

public static String removeHeadingSlashes(final String input)
{
    // .replaceFirst() or .replaceAll() will have the same effect, so...
    return HEADING_SLASHES.matcher(input).replaceFirst("");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to remove the leading slashes, not all slashes.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "////abc//def";
        System.out.println(url.replaceFirst("/+", ""));
    }

}
```

Comment: This will only work if there are two or more slashes

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String slashString = "//ab/c";

    System.out.println(slashString.replaceAll("^/+", ""));
}
```

output is:

> ab/c

Comment: That will remove *all* slashes, not just leading.

Comment: @user1803551 no it won't; note the ^ in the regex

Comment: @fge You should know to check the edit history at this point... :)